# scrapy httpcache not updating cache

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware

I'm using scrapy's httpcache and I expected the middleware to replace an existing cache that isn't fresh, but it's not.

The current behavior is: When the cached response has specific values on cookies, it fetches the page but the cached files aren't updated. Next time I run the crawler this behavior repeats.

The expected behavior is: When the cached response has specific values on cookies, it fetches the page and the cached files are updated. Next time I run the crawler it uses the cached response.

The policy code I'm using is like this:

```
import logging
from scrapy.utils.httpobj import urlparse_cached
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CustomPolicy:
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.ignore_schemes = settings.getlist('HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_SCHEMES')
        self.ignore_http_codes = [int(x) for x in settings.getlist('HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES')]

    def should_cache_request(self, request):
        return urlparse_cached(request).scheme not in self.ignore_schemes

    def should_cache_response(self, response, request):
        set_cookie = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')
        logger.debug(f'Response Cache DEBUG, url: {response.url}\nset_cookie: {set_cookie}')
        if not set_cookie or b'AUTH=removed' in set_cookie[0] or b'AUTH' not in set_cookie[0]:
            logger.info(f'Should not be cached, url: {response.url}')
            return False
        else:
            return response.status not in self.ignore_http_codes

    def is_cached_response_fresh(self, cachedresponse, request):
        set_cookie = cachedresponse.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')
        logger.debug(f'Cached Response DEBUG, url: {cachedresponse.url}\nset_cookie: {set_cookie}')
        if not set_cookie or b'AUTH=removed' in set_cookie[0] or b'AUTH' not in set_cookie[0]:
            logger.info(f'Cached Response is not fresh, url: {cachedresponse.url}')
            return False
        return True

    def is_cached_response_valid(self, cachedresponse, response, request):
        return True
```

My settings file is:

```
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
HTTPCACHE_DIR = <PATH>
HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
HTTPCACHE_POLICY = 'crawler.policies.CustomPolicy'
```